# How do I extract the unique values of a column to use them as a parameter in a function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to pass to a function one parameter, coming from an array like:

```
const array=[1,2,2,3]
```

I do not want to introduce manually every time my list of parameters, so I am fetching the data I want from a spreadsheet, getting the unique values of the column. These would be my desired array.

However, I get this error in function generate_Form_links(af_col):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

Here I get the column I want:

```
function getByName(colName) {
  const data=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1jogNOhdamVMXAlGyYOn9RXA2vNbrzNNJBUGhbL-EhTU').getSheets()[0]
  const [hA, ...vs]=data.getRange('E1:E13').getValues();
  let idx={};
  hA.forEach((h,i) => {idx[h]=i;});
  let oA=[];
  oA=vs.map(r=>r[idx[colName]]);
  Logger.log(oA.join('\n'))
  
}



var af_col=getByName('AF')
```

what could be wrong??

My function where I pass the parameter is:

```
function generate_Form_links(af_col){

  af_col.forEach(function(e, index){
    console.log(e, index)
    createForm(e)  //other function that create forms for each element of the given array  
  })
}
```

Comment: '_what could be wrong??_' just about everything, I'm afraid. (

Comment: It's hard to see how your code works together, but return data[col] should probably be return data[0][col]? Not sure why you would need that as it would equal to colName, but once again, hard to see how your code works together. Better post it as a continuous code snippet with comments

Comment: that error suggests that you don't have a header array (hA) What does you sheet look like.  Note I will not follow links to spreadsheets. Plus it's kind of of stupid thing to do to use a function that can select a column and then given only one column.  I think you misunderstand what your function does and since I'm the one that wrote it I'm pretty sure I'm right.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this simple example will be of some value.

Sheet0:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1,1 | 1,2 | 1,3 | 1,4 | 1,5 |
| 2,1 | 2,2 | 2,3 | 2,4 | 2,5 |
| 3,1 | 3,2 | 3,3 | 3,4 | 3,5 |
| 4,1 | 4,2 | 4,3 | 4,4 | 4,5 |

The Code to extract all values in COL3

```
  function getByName(colName) {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
    const [hA, ...vs] = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    let idx = {};
    hA.forEach((h, i) => { idx[h] = i; });
    let oA = [];//output array
    oA = vs.map(r => r[idx['COL3']]);
    Logger.log(oA.join('\n'))
  }

Execution log
4:50:57 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:50:58 PM  Info    1,3
2,3
3,3
4,3
4:50:58 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Thanks for your reproducible example! I tried to implement it as you said, but a new error is raised (I edited the question). Logger.log returns the values from the column correctly, but I get an error in the for loop with these values

Comment: Telling us that you have an error doesn't really help unless you provide the exact error message.